# Find all numbers $c$ that satisfy the conclusion of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = 4 \sin\ (2 \pi x),\ [-1,1]$$I'm not sure where to start on this problem. It's not simply the Mean Value Theorem where its $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{(b - a)}$? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Rolle's theorem is essentially the Mean Value Theorem, except it theorizes that, when $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=0$ over $(a,b)$, there will be some point "c" in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. What are $f(a)$ and $f(b)$? You can figure that out.

Comment: I found that both f(a) and f(b) both equal zero. Then I set the derivatve of f(x) equal to zero right? How would I solve for that equation?

Comment: @etree, use arccosine and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

To settle this problem, we will apply Rolle's theorem to our real-valued function f(x). The sine function is continuous on any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ thus $f(x)$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$. The derivative of $f(x)$ is given by 
\begin{equation*}
f'(x)=8\pi\cos(2\pi x).
\end{equation*}
Substituting the endpoints of the interval $(-1,1)$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
f'(1)=8\pi(1)=8\pi=8\pi(1)=f'(-1).
\end{equation*}
The sine function is differentiable on any interval of $\mathbb{R}$ thus differentiable on the interval $(-1,1)$. Also observe that substituting the endpoints into $f(x)$ gives us 
\begin{equation*}
4\sin(2\pi)=4\sin(-2\pi)\Rightarrow 4(0)=4(0)\Rightarrow 0=0
\end{equation*} 
thus $f(1)=f(-1).$ Applying Rolle's theorem, this implies that there exists some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
8\pi\cos(2\pi c)=0.
\end{equation*}
Rearranging for $c$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
\cos(2\pi c)=0\Rightarrow 2\pi c=\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{4}.
\end{equation*}
Thus $c=1/4$ is the only value for which we have $f'(c)=0$ on $[-1,1].~_{\square}$